# Enlarging image with a button?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

```
-(IBAction)bigger {

    must.bounds.size = CGSizeMake(must.bounds.size.width +5.0 , must.bounds.size.height +5.0);  
}
```

This is the code I input but I get the error saying that the expression is not assignable. Must is a uiimageview. I want to make each property (height and width) bigger by 5.0 each time i press the button. How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is to set the frame instead of the bounds. Do something like:

```
CGRect frame = must.frame;
frame.size.width += 5;
frame.size.height += 5;
must.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//here u can get the image as bigger without moving its center point


-(IBAction)bigger {


    CGRect _bounds = must.bounds;

    CGPoint centerPoint=must.center;

    _bounds.size = CGSizeMake(must.bounds.size.width + 5.0 , must.bounds.size.height + 5.0);

    must.bounds = _bounds;

    must.center = centerPoint;



}
```